# How to make nodemon exit on crash?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am using nodemon to restart node on changed files, but it also has this behavior which I don't want, it doesn't exit on crash. it says `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I want it to exit on crash because otherwise my docker container will report the container as healthy even if it crashed.

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/7d6c1a88a10f02d3f00b6e0635f982bb74ce5708/doc/cli/options.txt#L4 - don't know nodemon, but this option seems like something you described - handled here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/ed91703f0870660a3159749878c273e3e61e64a3/lib/monitor/run.js#L233

Comment: thanks, for some reason I couldn't find it in the --help and by googling.

Comment: Can this be solved with the flag "--exitcrash"?

Answer (score 3):

Try
`nodemon --exitcrash`

This worked for me in the docker container.